# Angular 2 Routing with a specific url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i'm currently working on an angular app which is opened on a particular url:

```
localhost:3000/?param1=abc,def&param2=abcdefghi
```

Now i want to implement angular routing .
So i have 2 routes : `1. mainComponent 2.dataComponent`

in my index.html ,have set the  as :

```
<base href="/">
```

After configuring the app to use routing , my app opens with only localhost:3000 , and even after adding the param1,param2 to the url , it is getting redirected to localhost:3000

How can i solve this ? as the parameters are passed only on opening the link and it is dynamic

**app.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'mainComponent', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'dataComponent',      component: DataComponent },
  {path : '' , component:MainComponent}
];
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/mainComponent" routerLinkActive="active">Main</a>
    <a routerLink="/dataComponent" routerLinkActive="active">Data</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your routes as following

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {path : '' ,redirectTo: 'mainComponent', pathMatch: 'full'},
 { path: 'mainComponent', component: MainComponent },
 { path: 'dataComponent',      component: DataComponent },
];
```

And better way to provide links

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['/mainComponent']" routerLinkActive="active">Main</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/dataComponent']" [queryParams]="{ param: "paramValue" } routerLinkActive="active">Data</a>
</nav>
```

To receive parameters you need to do following in your component constructor

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
    this.type = activatedRoute.snapshot.params['type'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply . i made the changes you mentioned , but after clicking on the ``Data`` , the url which had the parameters also vanished . is there any way the parameters are not removed on changing the route ?

Comment: Not by default - you will need to write a method to handle that using the `router.navigate()` method and attaching your current parameters. See this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Comment: @CruelEngine to pass query parameters you need to do this 

<a [routerLink]="['/dataComponent']" [queryParams]="{ param: "paramValue" } routerLinkActive="active">Data</a>

see my updated code